# Phoresis and mechanical vectors

Tags: zoology, ecology, symbiosis

According to wikipedia and [Human Parasitology](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=wsvKs8v9dvYC&pg=PA2&dq=phoresis&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=phoresis&f=false)
By Burton Jerome Bogitsh, Clint Earl Carter, Thomas N. Oeltmann

> Phoresis: In this type of symbiotic relationship, the phoront, usually the smaller organism, is mechanically carried by the other,usually larger organism the host.

**So can the host acting as a carrier be called a mechanical vector?**

On searching google.books I found some books mentioning:

<sub>Like Clinical parasitology</sub>

> Hosts that transmit parasites to man are vectors. Those that are essential in the life cycle are biologic vectors; those that are not essential ***are phoretic or mechanical vectors***.

Comment: Cheeky bump for my own paper: http://rstb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/372/1719/20160085 :)

Answer (score 1):

A mechanical vector just as biological vector transfers a parasite to its obligatory host but carrying it on the surface of its body while the host in phoresis is not necessarily carrying a phoront to an obligatory host (for parasitic interaction).

A parasite-mechanical vector relationship is possibly a kind of phoresis.